# Why do all the uncertainty relations have the units of action?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, dimensional-analysis, action

After a good chunk of time today working with natural units on another project, and later walking and pondering on the uncertainty relations from quantum mechanics: is there any fundamental reason that the units of the uncertainty relation should be the same units of action? I understand that the uncertainty relations all end up being $\propto \hbar$, (e.g. $\Delta E \Delta t \propto \hbar$) but is there any fundamental reason why this must be? Are there any uncertainty relations that do not have units of action?

Comment: Essentially a  duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28957/2451

Answer (score 1):

Actually since $\Delta A\Delta B\ge \frac{1}{2}\vert 
\langle [\hat A,\hat B]\rangle\vert$, it is entirely possible for the product of uncertainties to have dimension other than action.  For instance, if $\hat A=\hat L_z$ and $\hat B=\hat x$ then 
$$
\Delta L_z\Delta x\ge \frac{\hbar}{2}\vert\langle \hat y\rangle \vert
$$
and so the uncertainty would have units of [action]$\times$[position].  Likewise, $\Delta L_x\Delta L_y\ge \frac{\hbar}{2}\vert\langle \hat L_z\rangle\vert$ would have units of $\hbar^2$ since $\langle \hat L_z\rangle$ will have units of $\hbar$.