# Theoretical considerations on the conservation of energy and the conservation of linear momentum

Tags: energy-conservation, momentum, symmetry, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem

I report to you an interesting excerpt from my Physics book. 
It is an Italian version, so I apologize in advance, as I'm sure I won't give proper justice to its beauty in the translation as the authors would have done.

Talking about

> There is a profound theoretical connection between quantities that are preserved and symmetries of nature. So the principle of conservation of the linear momentum is related to the *spatial* symmetry of nature, which implies that an experiment done in a place give identical results to an equal experiment performed in any other place. [...] The principle of conservation of energy is related to the *temporal* symmetry: the result of an experiment today will be equal to the result of the same experiment did yesterday.

Physics I - Resnick, Halliday, Krane

After this words, the authors start talking about the conservations of the linear momentum in the canonical way. 
However, I was captured by this fly away and I want to find out more. How can I do that?

In synthesis:

1. *Spatial* symmetry of nature $~\Rightarrow~\ldots?? \ldots~\Rightarrow~$ Conservation of the linear momentum
2. *Temporal* symmetry of nature $~\Rightarrow~\ldots?? \ldots~\Rightarrow~$ 
   Conservation of energy

What do you think is in between?

Comment: The Noether Theorem is in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing "in between" is an [action principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_principle).

The most accessible explanation appears in Feynman's *The Character of Physical Law*. See [What's the interpretation of Feynman's picture proof of Noether's Theorem?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19847/whats-the-interpretation-of-feynmans-picture-proof-of-noethers-theorem)