# Invariance of action $\Rightarrow$ covariance of field equations?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, action, covariance, invariants

Invariance of action $\Rightarrow$ covariance of field equations? Is this statement true?

I have only seen examples of this, like the invariance of Electromagnetic action under Lorentz transformations.

How could we prove it?

The action is a scalar, $S$, so how I can't even transform it like $U^{-1}SU$...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this answer we formally show that a (quasi)symmetry of an action implies a corresponding symmetry of its EOM$^{\dagger}$. The answer does not discuss [form covariance](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=form+invariance) of EOM. For further relations between symmetries of action, EOM, and solutions of EOM, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51327/2451) Phys.SE post.

Let us first recall the definition of a *quasi-symmetry* of the action

$$ S_V[\phi]~:=~\int_V \! \mathbb{L}, \qquad \mathbb{L}~:=~{\cal L}~d^nx.\tag{1}$$

It means that the action (1) changes by a boundary integral

$$ S_{V^{\prime}}[\phi^{\prime}]
+\int_{\partial V^{\prime}} \!d^{n-1}x~(\ldots)
~=~S_V[\phi]+ \int_{\partial V} \!d^{n-1}x~(\ldots) \tag{2}$$

under the transformation. In the following we will assume that the spacetime integration region $V$ is arbitrary.

> Theorem. *If a local action functional $S_V[\phi]$ has a quasi-symmetry transformation
> $$ \phi^{\alpha}(x)~~\longrightarrow~~ \phi^{\prime \alpha}(x^{\prime}), \qquad  x^{\mu}~~\longrightarrow~~x^{\prime \mu}, \tag{3}$$
> then the EOM*
> $$ e_{\alpha}(\phi(x),\partial\phi(x),\ldots ; x)~:=~\frac{\delta S_V[\phi]}{\delta \phi^{\alpha}(x)}~\approx~0\tag{4}$$
> *must have a symmetry (wrt. the same transformation)*
> $$ e_{\alpha}(\phi^{\prime}(x^{\prime}),\partial^{\prime}\phi^{\prime}(x^{\prime}),\ldots ; x^{\prime})~\approx~e_{\alpha}(\phi(x),\partial\phi(x),\ldots ; x).\tag{5}$$

I) *Formal finite proof:*  This works both for a discrete and a continuous quasi-symmetry.

$$\begin{align}  e_{\alpha}&(\phi(x),\partial\phi(x),\ldots ; x)\cr
~:=~&\frac{\delta S_V[\phi]}{\delta \phi^{\alpha}(x)}\cr
~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~&\frac{\delta S_{V^{\prime}}[\phi^{\prime}]}{\delta \phi^{\alpha}(x)}\cr
~\stackrel{{\ddagger}}{\sim}~&\int_{V^{\prime}}\!d^nx^{\prime}~\frac{\delta S_{V^{\prime}}[\phi^{\prime}]}{\delta \phi^{\prime\alpha}(x^{\prime})} \frac{\delta \phi^{\prime\alpha}(x^{\prime})}{\delta \phi^{\alpha}(x)}\cr
~=~&\int_{V^{\prime}}\!d^nx^{\prime}~e_{\alpha}(\phi^{\prime}(x^{\prime}),\partial^{\prime}\phi^{\prime}(x^{\prime}),\ldots ; x^{\prime}) \frac{\delta \phi^{\prime\alpha}(x^{\prime})}{\delta \phi^{\alpha}(x)}.\end{align}  \tag{6}$$

II) *Formal infinitesimal proof:* This only works for a continuous quasi-symmetry. From the infinitesimal transformation (3)

$$\begin{align}  \delta \phi^{\alpha}(x)~:=~&\phi^{\prime \alpha}(x^{\prime})-\phi^{\alpha}(x), \cr
\delta x^{\mu}~:=~&x^{\prime \mu}-x^{\mu},\end{align} \tag{7}$$

we define a so-called *vertical* transformation

$$\begin{align}  \delta_0 \phi^{\alpha}(x)~:=~&\phi^{\prime \alpha}(x)-\phi^{\alpha}(x)\cr
~=~&\delta \phi^{\alpha}(x)-\delta x^{\mu} ~d_{\mu}\phi^{\alpha}(x),\cr  
d_{\mu}~:=~&\frac{d}{dx^{\mu}},\end{align} \tag{8}  $$

which transforms of the fields $\phi^{\alpha}(x)$ without transforming the spacetime points $x^{\mu}$. The quasi-symmetry implies that the Lagrangian $n$-form $\mathbb{L}$ transforms with a total spacetime derivative

$$\begin{align}  \delta \mathbb{L}~=~&d_{\mu} f^{\mu}~d^nx, \cr 
\delta_0 \mathbb{L}~=~&d_{\mu}(f^{\mu}-{\cal L}~\delta x^{\mu})~d^nx.\end{align} \tag{9} $$

The EOM (4) are typically of second order, so let us assume this for simplicity. (This assumption is not necessary.) Then the infinitesimal transformation of EOM (4) reads

$$\begin{align}  \delta e_{\alpha}(x)~=~&\delta_0 e_{\alpha}(x)
+\delta x^{\mu} ~\underbrace{d_{\mu} e_{\alpha}(x)}_{\approx 0}\cr
~\approx~&\delta_0 e_{\alpha}(x) \cr
~=~&\frac{\partial e_{\alpha}(x)}{\partial\phi^{\beta}(x)}\delta_0\phi^{\beta}(x)
+\sum_{\mu}\frac{\partial e_{\alpha}(x)}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi^{\beta}(x))}d_{\mu}\delta_0\phi^{\beta}(x)\cr
&+\sum_{\mu\leq \nu }\frac{\partial e_{\alpha}(x)}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\phi^{\beta}(x))}d_{\mu}d_{\nu}\delta_0\phi^{\beta}(x) \cr
~\stackrel{{\ddagger}}{\sim}~& \int_V\! d^ny~ \delta_0\phi^{\beta}(y)\frac{\delta e_{\alpha}(x)}{\delta \phi^{\beta}(y)}\cr
~=~&\int_V\! d^ny~ \delta_0\phi^{\beta}(y)\frac{\delta^2 S_V[\phi]}{\delta \phi^{\beta}(y)\delta \phi^{\alpha}(x)} \cr
~=~& \int_V\! d^ny~ \delta_0\phi^{\beta}(y)\frac{\delta^2 S_V[\phi]}{\delta \phi^{\alpha}(x)\delta\phi^{\beta}(y)} \cr
~=~& \frac{\delta}{\delta \phi^{\alpha}(x)} \int_V\! d^ny~ \delta_0\phi^{\beta}(y)\frac{\delta S_V[\phi]}{\delta \phi^{\beta}(y)} \cr
&-\int_V\! d^ny~ \frac{\delta(\delta_0\phi^{\beta}(y))}{\delta \phi^{\alpha}(x)} \frac{\delta S[\phi]}{\delta \phi^{\beta}(y)} \cr
~\sim~& \frac{\delta(\delta_0 S_V[\phi]) }{\delta \phi^{\alpha}(x)}  
-\int_V\! d^ny~ \frac{\delta(\delta_0\phi^{\beta}(y))}{\delta \phi^{\alpha}(x)} e_{\beta}(y) \cr ~\approx~& \frac{\delta(\delta_0 S_V[\phi]) }{\delta \phi^{\alpha}(x)}\cr
~=~&0. \end{align} \tag{10}$$

In the very last step of eq. (10) we used that the infinitesimal variation

$$\begin{align}  \delta_0 S_V[\phi]+\int_V\! d^nx~d_{\mu} \left({\cal L}~\delta x^{\mu} \right)  ~=~&\delta S_V[\phi]\cr
~=~&\int_{\partial V} \!d^{n-1}x~(\ldots)\end{align} \tag{11}$$

of the action is a boundary integral by assumption (2), so that its [functional derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) (10) must vanish (if it exists).

--

$^{\dagger}$ *Terminology and Notation:* Equations of motion (EOM) means [Euler-Lagrange equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) (1). The words *on-shell* and *off-shell* refer to whether EOM are satisfied or not. The $\approx$ symbol means equality modulo EOM.

$^{\ddagger}$ Warning: This step is *not* always justified. The $\sim$ symbol indicates that we have formally integrated by parts and ignored boundary contributions. Also we have assumed that the pertinent [functional derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) is well-defined and exists. This caveat is the main shortcoming of the formal proof given here. The point is quite serious, e.g. in the case of a global (=$x$-independent) variation, which typically doesn't vanish on the boundary. So boundary contributions could in principle play a role.

However, instead of using functional derivatives and integrations, it is possible to prove eq. (10) $x$-locally

$$\begin{align}  \delta_0 e_{\alpha}(x)~=~&\ldots
\cr~=~&\underbrace{E_{\alpha(0)} d_{\mu}}_{=0}\left(f^{\mu}(x)-{\cal L}(x)~\delta x^{\mu}\right)\cr 
&- \sum_{k\geq 0} d^k\left( \underbrace{e_{\beta}(x)}_{\approx 0} \cdot P_{\alpha(k)}\delta_0\phi^{\beta}(x) \right)\cr
 ~\approx~& 0  \end{align}\tag{12}$$

using only higher partial field derivatives

$$ P_{\alpha(k)} ~:=~\frac{\partial  }{\partial \phi^{\alpha(k)}}, \qquad k~\in~\mathbb{N}_0^n,\tag{13}$$

and higher Euler operators

$$ E_{\alpha(k)} ~:=~\sum_{m\geq k} 
\begin{pmatrix} m \cr k\end{pmatrix}
(-d)^m P_{\alpha(m)}, \tag{14}  $$

that all refer to the *same* spacetime point $x$. This $x$-local approach circumvent the problem of unaccounted boundary contributions.

Comment: I feel like everything should be clear, but I might not have all the elements to properly understand your answer.

Why is the EOM given by the formula in that theorem? The E-L equation is usually expressed in terms of the Lagrangian?

Also, I was asking about invariance of the action and subsequent covariance of the E-L equations, while it looks like you've shown that the action and the field equations share the same symmetries

Comment: I am not even sure I follow the $\delta(\delta S)$... do you know of a source where they explain how to take differentials of an already infinitesimal quantity?

Comment: form covariance = manifestly covariant?

Comment: @Harold, it is the basic theorem of calculus of variations (and the result is Euler-Lagrange equations). Clasical mechanics when put in action form, can be studied via calculus of variations thus the EOM are given by Euler-Lagrange equations

Comment: @Harold, firthermore equations can be covariant but not manifestly covariant. This means that their form may nclude non-symmetric terms (thus not manifestly covariant) however the terms as such that the action (or EOM) give same results under a symmetry transformation

Comment: As far as I understand if the action is invariant under a set of transformations (say the Lorentz transf) then its EOM will be covariant with said transformation, i.e. they will retain their functional form in the Lorentz-boosted/rotated frame. They will obviously be expressed in terms of the new basis vectors, but the functional form is identical.
I wanted to see a proof of this.