# Invariance of Lagrangian under Poincaré group transformations implies covariant Lagrange equations?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, action, covariance, invariants

I'm taking a class on classical fields and I came across a statement that I can't think about an argument to show that its true.

It says that *Invariance of a Lagrangian under transformations on Poincaré group ensures
the covariance of the Euler–Lagrange equations under these transformations.*

How can one prove this?

Comment: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144389/