# Principle of least action: $\frac{d S_{cl}}{dt_b} = \frac{\partial S_{cl}}{\partial t_b} + \frac{\partial S_{cl}}{\partial x_b}\dot{x}_b$

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, variational-principle, action

## Question

I cannot see how I can obtain the yellow highlighted section on the RHS from that of the LHS.

The following equation can be found in both my [lecture notes(*1)](http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~bjp/qt/qt.pdf) (page 9, equation 2.7) and is also used as Problem 2-6 in Feynman & Hibbs, *Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals*, (pg. 36),

$$
\require{color}
\tag{9}
\frac{d S_{cl}}{dt_b} = L(x_b,\dot{x}_b,t_b)
=
\colorbox{yellow}{
$\frac{\partial S_{cl}}{\partial t_b} + \frac{\partial S_{cl}}{\partial x_b}\dot{x}_b$
}
$$

Below, is the relevant section of notes used to derive the expression and also my own attempt at getting the expression on the RHS.

## Attempt

Using (8), and integrating both sides (not entirely sure I can actually do this!),

$$
\tag{13}
S_{cl} = p_b x_b
$$

so using product rule and again (8) for $p_b$ in the second term,

$$
\tag{14}
\frac{d S_{cl}}{dt_b}
=
\frac{d p_b}{d t_b}x_b + P_b\frac{d x_b}{d t_b}
=
\frac{d p_b}{d t_b}x_b + \frac{d S_{cl}}{d x_b}\dot{x_b}
$$

However, I have now two problems:

1. I have proper derivatives on the RHS, **not** partial derivatives
2. I can only obtain $S_{cl}$ in the first term by treating $x_b$ as independent of $t_b$ and using (14).

## Derivation

*This derivation copied directly from the [notes mentioned above](http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~bjp/qt/qt.pdf) on page 9. The relevant equation is (8)*

The action for a path $x(t)$,

$$
\tag{1}
S[ x ( t ) ] = \int^{t_b}_{t_a} L\left(x,\dot{x},t\right) dt
$$

where $L$ is the Lagrangian. Now, Using the principle of least action: the classical path $\bar{x}(t)$ is an extremum of the functional S,

$$
\tag{2}
\left.\frac{\delta{S}}{\delta{x}} \right|_{x=\bar{x}}= 0
$$

where $\delta{S}/\delta{x}$ is the functional derivative. For a small variation of the path: $x(t) \to x(t) + \delta x(t)$:

$$
\tag{3}
\delta S = S[x + \delta x] − S[x] = \int_{t_a}^{t_b} dt\ L\left(x + \delta{x},\dot{x} + \delta{\dot{x}},t\right) - L\left(x,\dot{x},t\right)
$$

Using 2D Taylor expansion around $\delta{x},\delta{\dot{x}}$ we get

$$
\tag{4}
\delta S
=
\int_{t_a}^{t_b} dt\ 
\left(
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}\delta x + \frac{\partial L}{\delta \dot{x}}\delta{\dot{x}}
\right)
+\mathcal{O}(\delta x^2)
$$
Now integrating by parts,

$$
\tag{5}
\delta S
=
\left[
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\delta{\dot{x}}
\right]^{t_b}_{t_a}
-
\int_{t_a}^{t_b} dt\ 
\left(
\frac{d}{dt}
\left(
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}
\right)
- \frac{\partial L}{\delta \dot{x}}
\right)
\delta x
+\mathcal{O}(\delta x^2)
$$

If the end-points of the path are fixed, i.e. $\delta x(t_a) = \delta x(t_b) = 0$, then the we obtain Lagrange’s equation for the classical path,
$$
\tag{6}
\frac{d}{dt}
\left(
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}
\right)
- \frac{\partial L}{\delta \dot{x}}
=0
$$

Considering the value of the action $S$ on the classical path, $S_{cl} \equiv S[\bar{x}(t)]$: $S_{cl}$ will be a function of the end points, i.e. of $x_a, t_a, x_b$, and $t_b$.

Varying the endpoint $(x_b, t_b)\to (x_b, t_b) + (\delta x_b, \delta t_b)$, but keep $(x_a, t_a)$ fixed. Lagrange’s equation holds for the classical path. We choose $\delta t_b = 0$ and remember canonical momentum $p$ conjugate to $x$ as $p = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}$ to get,

$$
\tag{7}
\delta S_{cl} =
\left[
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\delta{\dot{x}}
\right]^{t_b}_{t_a}
=
\left[
p\delta x
\right]^{t_b}_{t_a}
=
p(t_b)\delta x_b −p(t_a)\delta x_a =p(t_b)\delta x_b
$$
Hence,

$$
\tag{8}
\frac{\partial S_{cl}}{\partial x_b} = p_b
$$

Now considering $\frac{dS_{cl}}{dt}$. From (1) we may write:

$$
\require{color}
\tag{9}
\frac{d S_{cl}}{dt_b} = L(x_b,\dot{x}_b,t_b)
=
\colorbox{yellow}{
$\frac{\partial S_{cl}}{\partial t_b} + \frac{\partial S_{cl}}{\partial x_b}\dot{x}_b$
}
$$

This gives,

$$
\tag{11}
\frac{\partial S_{cl}}{\partial t_b} = L − p_b\dot{x}_b =−E_b
$$
$$
\tag{12}
E_b = -\frac{\partial S_{cl}}{\partial t_b}
$$
where $E_b$ is the *energy function* or *Hamiltonian*.

## References

(*1) Brian Pendleton, Quantum Theory, The University of Edinburgh, 2015

Answer (score 1):

Comments to the question (v3):

1. The boundary data $x_b$, $t_b$, $x_a$, $t_a$ are independent variables in the on-shell action $S_{\rm cl}(x_b,t_b;x_a,t_a)$, and we assume it makes sense to take partial derivatives wrt. each of them.
2. One can in general not give a closed formula for the on-shell action $S_{\rm cl}(x_b,t_b;x_a,t_a)$ (that doesn't somehow refer to the off-shell action), only in special cases.
3. OP's question is essentially about the proof of the Lemma in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/19944/2451).
4. It should probably be stressed that Ref. 1 implicitly assumes in the *total* time differentiation 
   $$\frac{d S_{\rm cl}(x_b(t_b),t_b;x_a,t_a)}{dt_b} ~=~ L(x_b,\dot{x}_b(x_b,t_b;x_a,t_a),t_b), \qquad \tag{btwn 2.6 and 2.7 }$$
   that the variation of boundary conditions is *along the same* classical path, see my above mentioned Phys.SE answer for details.

References:

1. Brian Pendleton, *Quantum Theory Lecture Notes,* University of Edinburgh, September 2015. The pdf file is available [here](http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~bjp/qt/qt.pdf).

Comment: This has helped me a little but still unable to see where you obtained eq. (13) in your SE answer that is linked

Comment: Which step in eq. (13)?

Comment: The bit that required the relation below that I did not know! I appreciated your detailed explanations on the linked answer though

Answer (score 0):

Taken directly from [this link](https://www.pdx.edu/nanogroup/sites/www.pdx.edu.nanogroup/files/Chapter_4__Hamilton_Variational_principle__Hamilton%20Jacobi_Eq_Classical_Mechanics_1.pdf) "From the Hamilton’s Variational Principle to the Hamilton Jacobi Equation", PSU-Physics Lecture Notes...

For an arbitrary function, $S = S(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}, t)$,

$$
\frac{dS}{dt}
=
\dot{\mathbf{u}}
\frac{\partial S}{\partial \mathbf{u}}
+
\dot{\mathbf{v}}
\frac{\partial S}{\partial \mathbf{v}}
+
\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}
$$
using,
$$
\frac{\partial S}{\partial \mathbf{u}} =
\left(
\frac{\partial S}{\partial u_1},
\frac{\partial S}{\partial u_2},
\frac{\partial S}{\partial u_3}
\right)
$$

This solves the whole problem. It was simply that I did not know the above relation.

Comment: Another reason for the advantage of [index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_notation), as one can write ${\rm d}S/{\rm d}t=\dot{u}_i\partial S/\partial u_i+\cdots$ for $i\in(1,3)$ (or 0,3 for 4D).

Comment: Nice :) I'll leave it as the above to keep it straight forward to read though

Comment: That formula is the chain rule for functions with explicit $t$-dependence, cf. e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9122/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks for naming it. I was struggling to find its proof