# Classical action

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, variational-principle, action

Any idea how to solve this problem?

> In classical mechanics, the action $S$ is defined as
>   $$S[q(t)] = \int_{t_0}^t L(q(t'), \dot q(t'), t')\; dt'$$
>   where $L$ is the Lagrangian function (also called Lagrangian) and $q$ is some generalized coordinate of the system.
>
> a) ...
>
> b) For classical paths with a fixed starting point $q(\tau_0) = q_0$, one can interpret $S$ as a function of $q_{\tau}$ and $\tau$, i.e. $S = S(q_{\tau}, \tau)$.
>
> Show that
>   $$\frac{\partial S}{\partial q_{\tau}}=p_{\tau}\;, \qquad \;\;\frac{\partial S}{\partial \tau}=-H$$
>   where $H$ is the Hamiltonian function of the system.
>
> Hint: For some fixed starting point $q_0$, each path can be parametrized by some
>   arbitrary point $q_{\tau}$ on that path such that $q(t)$ itself can be thought of as a function of both $q_{\tau}$ and some general time $t$.

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) We are happy to answer conceptual questions you have about solving the problem, but normally no one is going to just do a problem for you without you showing your efforts and asking about specific steps/issues you have with solving the problem.

Comment: This question (v3) is explained in a Lemma of my Phys.SE answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/19944/2451).