# Derivative of Action

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, action

**How to show that partial derivative of action is Energy.**
action of system $S[q_1,q_2, t_1, t_2]$ is integral by time of system Lagrangian. I need to show that partial derivatives by $t_1$ and $t_2$ is Energy.

$$\frac{\partial S }{\partial t_1} = - \frac{\partial S }{\partial t_2} = E$$

Comment: Please read [how to ask homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and edit this question to comply with it.

Comment: How have you attacked this problem thus far?

Comment: I have given homework in university. First I had to find action of given system lagrangian using euler-lagrange theorem and find derivatives by q1 q2 t1 and t2. Now I need to generalize it.

Comment: This question (v3) is explained in a Lemma of my Phys.SE answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/19944/2451).