Variational approach to problem $1.14$ from Goldstein
To summarize, the problem states that we prove
$$\mathcal L'=\mathcal L+\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}F(\mathbf q,t)$$
is also a valid Lagrangian, that is, it satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equations for each coordinate (assuming $F$ is at least $\mathcal C^2$).
I've seen a solution online in which they just substitute $\mathcal L'$ in the E-L equations and prove they're identical to $0$ $\forall i$:
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal L'}{\partial q_i}-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\partial \mathcal L'}{\partial \dot q_i}=\cdots=\underbrace{\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial q_i}-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \dot q_i}}_0+\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\frac{\mathrm d F}{\mathrm dt}-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\partial F}{\partial q_i}}_0=0$$
Instead, what my professor did today to solve this problem was simply proving
$$\delta S=\delta\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\mathcal L'\,\mathrm dt=0$$
In fact it is pretty straightforward to follow from here:
\begin{align}
\delta S&=\delta\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\mathcal L'\,\mathrm dt\\
&=\delta\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\mathcal L\,\mathrm dt+\delta\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}F\,\mathrm dt\\
&=0+\delta[F(\mathbf q(t),t)|_{t_1}^{t_2}\\
&=\delta F(\mathbf q(t_2),t_2)-\delta F(\mathbf q(t_1),t_1)\overset{?}{=}0
\end{align}
but the issue arises when trying to prove the last line... Do I just assume the variation of a constant is $0$ and that's it? Or was the penultimate step incorrect?

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87628/2451


In fact it is pretty straightforward to follow from here:
\begin{align}
\delta S&=\delta\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\mathcal L'\,\mathrm dt\\
&=\delta\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\mathcal L\,\mathrm dt+\delta\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}F\,\mathrm dt\\
&=0+\delta[F(\mathbf q(t),t)|_{t_1}^{t_2}\\
&=\delta F(\mathbf q(t_2),t_2)-\delta F(\mathbf q(t_1),t_1)\overset{?}{=}0
\end{align}
but the issue arises when trying to prove the last line... Do I just assume the variation of a constant is $0$ and that's it? Or was the penultimate step incorrect?

The variational method starts from the assumption that the endpoints are fixed.
So, the variations of interest here can't change $q_2$ or $q_1$.
So, $\delta F(q_2,t_2)=0$ and $\delta F(q_1,t_1)=0$ are both individually zero. And so too their difference is zero.

Thanks, do you suggest there are cases where the endpoints aren't fixed? If so could you provide an example? Maybe time dependent or spatial dependent endpoints?

You can certainly consider cases where the endpoints are not fixed and thereby derive relationships like $\frac{\partial S}{\partial q_i}=-p_i$ and (somewhat more amazingly) $\frac{\partial S}{\partial t_i}=E_i$

See also, Lemma Eq. 10 of this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19847/whats-the-interpretation-of-feynmans-picture-proof-of-noethers-theorem/19944#19944
