# How can I find the normalization constant of probability amplitude for small space-time path?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, path-integral, dirac-delta-distributions, normalization

For free particle with $V=0$ case we get
$$<x_n,t_n;x_{n-1},t_{n-1}>=\frac{1}{w(\Delta t)}\exp \left [\frac{im(x_n-x_{n-1})^2}{2\hbar\Delta t}\right ] \tag{6.42}$$
given in eqn. 6.42 of Sakurai (2nd Edition p.127).

Then given
$$<x_n,t_n;x_{n-1},t_{n-1}>|_{t_n=t_{n-1}} = \delta(x_n - x_{n-1})\tag{6.43}$$
in equation 6.43.

Then say we obtain
$$\frac{1}{w(\Delta t)}=\sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi i \hbar \Delta t}}.\tag{6.44}$$

How can I find the following constant without using "Propagator concept"?

Answer (score 3):

1. The Feynman fudge factor (6.44) follows from the normalization (6.43) and the [heat-kernel representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Semigroups) (6.42) of the Dirac delta distribution (after a [Wick rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation)).
2. Alternatively, the Feynman fudge factor (6.44) can be derived from the Hamiltonian phase space path integral, cf. e.g. section V in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/81278/2451).