# Gelfand Yaglom Theorem (boundary conditions)

Tags: mathematics

I have one question about the Gelfand Yaglom Theorem.
Typically I see people who want to calculate the determinant of a Schrödinger Operator $\hat{\cal{M}}_{{\rm S}} = -\frac{{\rm d}^2}{{\rm d}t^2} + U(t)$ and then solve 
\begin{align} \hat{\cal{M}}_{\rm S} \, \phi = 0 \end{align}
with the boundary conditions $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi'(0)=1$.
From a paper from Kirsten I know that in this case $\phi'(0)=1$ is for convenience in order for a contribution at $\infty$ in the $\lambda$-plane to vanish.
I'm however wondering what happens if I consider a more general Sturm-Liouville type equation with the Operator $\hat{\cal{M}}_{{\rm SL}} = -\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \, g(t) \, \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} + U(t)$.
Now here it seems to be that the "convenient" boundary conditions are $\phi'(0)=\frac{1}{g(0)}$ (see Kleinert Pathintegrals p. 134).
I haven't been able to figure out why this is so though...

Comment: [More on Gelfand-Yaglom theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12322/2451).

Comment: I know this thread, but it did not help me...